# Yeoman : angular-fullstack-generator cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman, babeljs

i've been trying to use Yeoman to scaffold a mean app with angular-fullstack-generator, however i've been encountering this weird error i'd never encountered before, i've already tried reinstalling grunt-cli, npm, yo, none of it works, i'm using NVM and Node 4.4.0

I have Python 2.7.11 installed, apparently the 32-bit version, whereas everything else is 64-bit, i don't know if this might be what's causing the problem.

The full description of the error as shown on the console is as follows:

```
   yo angular-fullstack
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-angular-fullstack\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:3:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

So, what am i doing wrong here? Is there anything else i can try to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the `babel-runtime` module is missing. The `babel-runtime` module is required for `babel` to work.

You can fix this by running the command:

`npm install --save babel-runtime`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it uninstalling and removing babel from node global dependencies and then reinstalling yo and generatog-angular-fullstack.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, it couldn't find gulp-babel, so I installed the module globally.

`$ npm install -g --save gulp-babel`

And if you're using a mac you may want to try to put `sudo` in front of the command.